# React access props from inside a javascript event listener

Tags: reactjs

I am using an external javascript library inside my React app.

That library dispatches events and I have added the appropriate listener for those events.
I am now trying to access the React props from inside the event handler.
Is it possible to access those  ?

I obviously cannot use 'this' because the context has switched to document from inside the event handler.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import config from 'react-global-configuration';

export default class Meeting extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);

  }
  componentDidMount() {

  document.addEventListener('onLocalMediaElementAdded', function (e) {
      console.log('event fired');
      //I NEED TO ACCESS PROPS HERE
    }, false);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="meeting">
        <div id="container"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use an arrow function to maintain the scope.

So

```js
document.addEventListener('onLocalMediaElementAdded', (e) => {
  console.log('event fired');
  //I NEED TO ACCESS PROPS HERE
  console.log(this.props); // it works now
}, false);
```

Comment: Should this still work with React Hooks? It seems it doesn't in my case

Comment: @riccardolardi you should post a question with your specific case.